# How to add more element with PHP XMLWriter?

Tags: php, xmlwriter

My code:

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openURI('data.xml');
$writer->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');  
$writer->startElement("cont");
$writer->writeElement('product', $produto);  
$writer->writeElement('price', $preco); 
$writer->endDocument();
$writer->flush();
```

Output:

```
Product: CD
Price: 10,00
```

How do I add an element without deleting the last element?

I want this xml return.

```
Product: CD2
Price: 20,00
Product: CD
Price: 10,00
Product...
```

Comment: what you mean by *without deleting the last element?*

Comment: Call `$writer->writeElement` as many times as you need.

Comment: Why is your output not XML-formatted ?

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam, which refers to a new element without having to exclude the previous one. The example is not xml, but the output is in XML.